# Importing a function from a classless module in a class

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hello from a python newbie.
I searched around here for an answer to my question but didn't find anything so I thought I would ask.

I have a classless module, let's call it module_one.py which contains a function.

```
def function_one(a=None, b=None):
    c = a + b
    return c
```

Now I want to use function_one in another module (which is located in the same file) that actually contains a class:

```
from module_one import function_one
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = "Hello"

    def function_two(self):
        self.function_one(a=1, b=2)
```

When I try to do something like that I get an error that says:
AttributeError: 'Example' object has no attribute 'function_one'

What am I doing wrong? should I somehow declare 'function_one' in **init**? If yes, how? I did several tries but all of them failed. Sorry for my silly question. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since `function_one` isn't a method defined in the class `Example` you don't use the `self` identifier.

```
from module_one import function_one
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = "Hello"

    def function_two(self):
        function_one(a=1, b=2)
```